# Error when creating a new project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I create a new project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Express I get a error.

> The project file could not loaded. '.' hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 21, position 1.
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets

I have reinstalled Visual Studio and reinstalled .NET. How can I fix this error?

Comment: @Ormoz don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: You need to get your machine fixed before you can install VS.  Replacing the disk drive is highly recommended.  If you want to recover it then ask at superuser.com

Comment: Which project types? Can you post the xaml files content? Try a DevEnv /reset ?

Comment: C# console app is for school

Answer (score 0):

Try to change encoding of the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets` file to UTF-8.

Comment: Cant change it and I don't know where to find devenv

Comment: I have switched to xamarin studio WAY better